# How to ask user input quantities and the arrays elements in the same line?

Tags: python, user-input

I want to make the user input how much elements they want to input and the elements itself on the same line.
Ex:

```
5 2 4 6 8 10
```

`5` is the quantities and `2,4,6,8,10` are the elements.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: if it's all on the same line, why would you need to first input to be the number of elements wanted ?

Comment: you can do `a, *b = input().split()`, but I'm not sure why you want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
n, *list_ = map(int, input().split())
print(n, list_)
```

this will give you `n` (an integer denoting no. of elements), and `list_` containing the n integers.

Note: taking `n` as input in this case is redundant so consider dropping it. You can always check length of list by using `len()`

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways to do this.
If it is ok for the user to enter a comma-separated list, then `eval` is very helpful. This will automatically convert the values to floats/integers.

```
user_in = input('Enter input: ')
user_data = eval(user_in)
num_eles = user_data[0]
```

If you strictly want the user to input space-delimited data, then do something similar, but requires more work.

```
user_in = input('Enter input: ')
user_data = [int(x) for x in user_in.split(' ')]
num_eles = user_data[0]
```

Like one of the comments mentioned, it probably isn't necessary for the user to input the number of elements because you could just do:

```
num_eles = len(user_data)
```